# Swift UI - animation - terrible performances

Tags: performance, swiftui

I'm trying to display an automatic scrolling text (marquee?) with an animation using Swift UI.
When the mouse is over the text, the animation stops (that's why I store the current state of the animation).
Using one of the latest M1 MBP, this simple animation is using up to 10% of CPU and I'm trying to understand why. Is Swift UI not made for animations like this one or am I doing something wrong? At the end, it's just an animation moving the x offset.

Here is the code of my Marquee.

```swift
import SwiftUI

private enum MarqueeState {
    case idle
    case animating
}

struct GeometryBackground: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Color.clear.preference(key: WidthKey.self, value: geometry.size.width)
        }
    }
}

struct WidthKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat(0)
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
    
    typealias Value = CGFloat
}

extension View {
    func myOffset(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) -> some View {
        return modifier(_OffsetEffect(offset: CGSize(width: x, height: y)))
    }
    
    func myOffset(_ offset: CGSize) -> some View {
        return modifier(_OffsetEffect(offset: offset))
    }
}

struct PausableOffsetX: GeometryEffect {
    @Binding var currentOffset: CGFloat
    @Binding var contentWidth: CGFloat
    private var targetOffset: CGFloat = 0.0;
    
    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { targetOffset }
        set { targetOffset = newValue }
    }
    
    init(targetOffset: CGFloat, currentOffset: Binding<CGFloat>, contentWidth: Binding<CGFloat>) {
        self.targetOffset = targetOffset
        self._currentOffset = currentOffset
        self._contentWidth = contentWidth
    }
    
    
    public func effectValue(size: CGSize) -> ProjectionTransform {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.currentOffset = targetOffset
        }
        let relativeOffset = targetOffset.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: contentWidth)
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: relativeOffset, y: 0)
        
        return ProjectionTransform(transform)
    }
}

struct Marquee<Content: View> : View {
    @State private var isOver: Bool = false
    
    private var content: () -> Content
    
    @State private var state: MarqueeState = .idle
    @State private var contentWidth: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var isAppear = false
    @State private var targetOffsetX: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var currentOffsetX: CGFloat
    
    public init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
        self.currentOffsetX = 0
    }
    
    private func getAnimation() -> Animation {
        let duration = contentWidth / 30
        print("animation with duration of ", duration)
        return Animation.linear(duration: duration).repeatForever(autoreverses: false);
    }
    
    public var body : some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                if isAppear {
                    content()
                        .overlay(GeometryBackground())
                        .fixedSize()
                    
                    content()
                        .overlay(GeometryBackground())
                        .fixedSize()
                }
            }
            
            .modifier(PausableOffsetX(targetOffset: targetOffsetX, currentOffset: $currentOffsetX, contentWidth: $contentWidth))
            .onPreferenceChange(WidthKey.self, perform: { value in
                if value != self.contentWidth {
                    self.contentWidth = value
                    print("Content width = \(value)")
                    resetAnimation()
                }
            })
            .onAppear {
                self.isAppear = true
                resetAnimation()
            }
            .onDisappear {
                self.isAppear = false
            }
            .onHover(perform: { isOver in
                self.isOver = isOver
                checkAnimation()
            })
        }
        .frame(width: 400)
        .clipped()
    }
    
    private func getOffsetX() -> CGFloat {
        switch self.state {
            case .idle:
                return self.currentOffsetX
            case .animating:
                return -self.contentWidth + currentOffsetX
        }
    }
    
    private func checkAnimation() {
        if isOver{
            if self.state != .idle {
                pauseAnimation()
            }
        } else {
            if self.state != .animating {
                resumeAnimation()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func pauseAnimation() {
        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0)) {
            self.state = .idle
            self.targetOffsetX = getOffsetX()
        }
    }
    
    private func resumeAnimation() {
        print("Resume animation");
        withAnimation(getAnimation()) {
            self.state = .animating
            self.targetOffsetX = getOffsetX()
        }
    }
    
    private func resetAnimation() {
        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0)) {
            self.currentOffsetX = 0
            self.targetOffsetX = 0
            self.state = .idle
        }
        resumeAnimation()
    }
}
```

And we can use it as follow:

```swift
Marquee {
            Text("Hello, world! Hello, world! Hello, world! Hello, world!").padding().fixedSize()
        }.frame(width: 300)
```

**EDIT**
I ended up using Core Animation instead of the one built in Swift UI. The cpu / Energy impact is an absolute zero. So I wouldn't recommend using Swift UI animation for long lasting or persistant animations.

Comment: There is a GitHub repo [Marquee](https://github.com/SwiftUIKit/Marquee) that seems to do this and more in a much simpler fashion. I haven't used it or tested it for overhead, but it should give you something to compare to.

Comment: Yes, I wrote mine based on the one you suggest but it has the same performance issue.

Comment: Running the Marquee package on an older Intel. I am seeing <1% CPU usage. No spikes. Not sure if it is your test app or an M1 problem.

Comment: Hum... I tried the Marquee package and I got 7 to 8% cpu usage with the same string as in my example. Screenshot here: https://ibb.co/tbRZbkG

Comment: I am inclined to go with an M1 issue...

Comment: Have you tested it on an actual device?

Comment: It is an Mac Os application. I'm currently trying to test it on my wife Intel MBP and I'll share the results...

Comment: That would have been helpful to know. Retested on Xcode 13.2.1, MacOS 12.1. No difference from iOS 15.2.

Comment: So, I installed latest Xcode version on my wife's Intel MPB and got the same results. https://ibb.co/c8860S5. Looks like it's related to Mac OS...

Comment: Tested it with ios and I'm getting between 0 & 4% cpu usage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242529/discussion-between-yrb-and-vincent).

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I am struggling with the same issue. I have a simple marquee view based on GeometryReader, and the performance is awful - both in simulator and on a real iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions for improvement include optimizing the view hierarchy, avoiding unnecessary state changes, optimizing images, utilizing hardware acceleration, addressing memory management issues, profiling with Instruments, testing on various devices, considering Core Animation for complex animations, and ensuring the use of the latest SwiftUI versions and Xcode.